# Threads work inappropriately

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, pthreads, posix

I'm writing this code in c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct
{
    int customerID;
    int ticketNumber;
    sem_t * freeCashiers;
    sem_t Cashiers[2];
}Customer;

int firstIsFree = 1;
int secondIsFree = 1;

void * buyTheTickets(void * data)
{
    Customer * currentCustomer = (Customer *)data;
    int ID = currentCustomer->customerID;

    currentCustomer->ticketNumber = rand()%15+1;

    sem_wait(currentCustomer->freeCashiers);    

    sem_wait(&(currentCustomer->Cashiers[0]));

    if(firstIsFree)
    {
        firstIsFree = 0;
        printf("First Cashier Sold %d Ticket To %d Customer\n",currentCustomer->ticketNumber,ID);

        usleep(1000000);
        firstIsFree = 1;

        sem_post(&(currentCustomer->Cashiers[0]));
        sem_post(currentCustomer->freeCashiers);

        return 0;
    }

    sem_post(&(currentCustomer->Cashiers[0]));

    sem_wait(&(currentCustomer->Cashiers[1]));

    if(secondIsFree)
    {
        secondIsFree = 0;
        printf("Second Cashier Sold %d Ticket To %d Customer\n",currentCustomer->ticketNumber,ID);

        usleep(1000000);
        secondIsFree = 1;

        sem_post(&(currentCustomer->Cashiers[1]));
        sem_post(currentCustomer->freeCashiers);

        return 0;
    }
    sem_post(&(currentCustomer->Cashiers[1]));
}

int main()
{
    int numberOfCustomers = 15;
    sem_t * numberOfCashiers = (sem_t*)malloc(sizeof(sem_t));
    sem_init(numberOfCashiers,0,2);
    sem_t first;
    sem_t second;
    sem_init(&first,0,1);
    sem_init(&second,0,1);

    for(int i=1;i<=numberOfCustomers;i++)
    {
        pthread_t * curTh = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
        Customer * curCu = (Customer *)malloc(sizeof(Customer));
        curCu->customerID = i;
        curCu->freeCashiers = numberOfCashiers;
        curCu->Cashiers[0] = first;
        curCu->Cashiers[1] = second;
        pthread_create(curTh,NULL,buyTheTickets,curCu);     
    }

    pthread_exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

And it gives output:

```
First Cashier Sold 14 Ticket To 1 Customer

Second Cashier Sold 2 Ticket To 2 Customer

First Cashier Sold 13 Ticket To 3 Customer

Second Cashier Sold 11 Ticket To 4 Customer

First Cashier Sold 9 Ticket To 5 Customer

Second Cashier Sold 11 Ticket To 6 Customer

First Cashier Sold 2 Ticket To 7 Customer

Second Cashier Sold 13 Ticket To 8 Customer

First Cashier Sold 10 Ticket To 9 Customer

Second Cashier Sold 2 Ticket To 10 Customer

First Cashier Sold 3 Ticket To 11 Customer

Second Cashier Sold 8 Ticket To 12 Customer

First Cashier Sold 6 Ticket To 13 Customer

Second Cashier Sold 5 Ticket To 14 Customer

First Cashier Sold 9 Ticket To 15 Customer
```

The Question is that if the second thread goes after`sem_wait(&(currentCustomer->Cashiers[0]));`  It means `sem_post(&(currentCustomer->Cashiers[0]));` this already happened so firstIsFree is already 1 so why does it print the second printf?

Comment: For which occasion you want to dress it? ... ;)

Comment: @LPs didn't get the question, new in this field, can you ask it another way?

Comment: Well. It was a joke: [inappropriate](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/inappropriate). I'm looking at your code. I'll be back to you if I see something.

Comment: The question was an ironic comment pointing out that your code is not well formatted and therefore difficult to read.

Comment: @LajosArpad code in my editor looks good but when i paste it here, it becomes chaotic, sry not my fault.

Comment: I'm not really getting your code. BTW you are using semaphores but you are also using globals: `firstIsFree`, `secondIsFree`. You have a race condition there.

Comment: @LPs my goal was to code a simulation of a market where there are 2 cashiers and 15 customers, if any of the cashiers are free customers go and buy ticket from them. and process goes simultaneously

Comment: Though your goal seems that customers should go to either of the 2 cashiers, but, as per your code, you seem to always want them to go to first cashier first and then to the second cashier. Why?

Comment: @Jay It seems I'm not doing it right, I just don't have idea how to do it properly.

Comment: @GiorgiCercvadze, it is your fault. If the code looks like this after you paste it, then why don't you beautify it? Luckily your question was edited to make it readable, kudos to LPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below issue is present in your code which could lead to undefined behaviour. Please correct it and try the execution again:

In your main function, you are using local variables for semaphores `first` and `second` and your main function seems to exit without waiting for the threads to exit. You need to have `pthread_join` calls in your main function.

Comment: Add a loop in main function, immediately after your pthread_create loop and call pthread_join for all the created threads.

Comment: You totally right, but there isn't _the risk_: it is a concrete behavior.

Comment: @LPs, Can you explain further? What do you mean by "it is a concrete behavior"?

Comment: Probably a false friend: I mean it is the real behavior: surely the two semaphores, that have local scopes in main, are not accessible after `pthread_exit(0);`